# OpenGL 4.0 vs AMD Radeon 7400M and Visual Studio, a story about working together

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, gpu, opengl-4

I've got two cards on my laptop, an integrated Intel one and a Radeon 7400M series.

Apparently, even if you set your computer to open Visual Studio with the AMD card, when running applications, AMD doesn't recognize that the exe should also run with the dedicated card, so one must set the "appName.exe" to run with the GPU rather than Visual Studio itself.

I'll be writing quite a few OpenGL apps in the near future, and I would like to know if anyone knows of any simpler way to make sure everything's running on the dedicated card rather than the integrated. If not, thats fine, its only one extra step anyways.

Comment: That makes sense. The "application" is a *separate* process. Doesn't matter if it was VS that launched it, a shortcut, or some command line. (There is support for parent processes in the Windows kernel, but this is simply not used in a decision process by the video drivers - there is no "or parent name is.." AFAIK.)

Comment: which does make sense, yes, i was just wondering if there was any way to change that.